# Nav not collapsing in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a bootstrap site [http://soygarota.com/blog/public](http://www.soygarota.com/blog/public)

and I checked serveral times the code, is added the bootstrap.min.css, the bootstrap.min.js and jquery, but for some reason the header nav is not collapsing when I use a mobile devices or the Google Inspector.

Here is the code of my header nav

```
<div class="masthead hidden-sm">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/layout/header.JPG') }}" class="img-responsive logo-header-img"/>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse text-center sin-bordes" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="navbar-header text-center">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center
">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                <li><a href="{{ Route('front.index') }}" class="HeaderLink">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route('front.search.category', 'INSPIRATION')}}" class="HeaderLink">INSPIRATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route('front.search.category', 'LIFESTYLE')}}" class="HeaderLink">LIFESTYLE</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route('front.search.category', 'FASHION')}}" class="HeaderLink">FASHION</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('front.about') }}" class="HeaderLink">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('front.contact') }}" class="HeaderLink">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'front.index', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'navbar-form','role' => 'search']) !!}
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="SearchInput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="SearchIcon"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SEARCH" name="srch_term" id="srch_term">
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>


        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->


    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey try setting this in your head tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you want a little more info on how this works check out this 
[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: It breaks all the design